# Can an IP address end in 255 and not be a broadcast IP address?

Tags: networking, ip

Typically if an IP address ends in 255, that will be a broadcast IP.

This is true for a /24 network. But in a /17 network for example, can an IP address for a computer end in 255, or will that always be a broadcast IP address?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, if the IP address ending in `.255` is not the highest IP in the subnet IP range. No if the IP address ending in `.255` is the highest IP address in the subnet IP range.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, an IPv4 address can end in 255 without being a broadcast address. For it to be a broadcast address, all bits in the host part need to be ones. In your example, the 32-17 = 15 rightmost bits need to be all ones, not only the rightmost eight. For example, `10.0.0.255` in a `10.0.0.0/17` network is not a broadcast address, since the netmask is `255.255.128.0`. The broadcast address in this case would be `10.0.127.255`.

Comment: Well, the broadcast address in your example still ends with `.255`.

Comment: @Matthias So? I didn't say the broadcast address doesn't end in `255`, I just answered the question by giving an example of an IP address ending in `255` that is not a broadcast address. By the way, the opposite is also true: an address does not need to end in `255` and still be a broadcast address. For example `10.0.0.15` is the broadcast address in the `10.0.0.0/28` subnet.