# Bash - Increment IP address but consider the subnet mask?

Tags: bash

I have a file storing the last used local IP address that i have set to a client of my VPN. I'm automating the process of adding new clients, so i want to read the IP that i have used for the last client and increment the address to use for the next client.

However, this must be sensitive in regards to the subnet used. I use a /8 subnet for a 10.0.0.0 RFC 1918 private network.

So, say the last client's IP was 10.0.0.5. After incrementing, i should get 10.0.0.6.

When the last client IP reaches 10.0.0.254, instead of incrementing to 10.0.0.255, we should instead get 10.0.1.1 and so on. As the subnet provides all octets except the leading one (10.) for use by clients, we should go this way for the entire range, e.g.:

After 10.0.1.254 -> 10.0.2.1

After 10.0.254.254 -> 10.1.0.1

I'm looking for the simplest way to do this. Could this be done with a one liner?

Comment: What's wrong with 255? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407389/can-an-ip-address-end-in-255-and-not-be-a-broadcast-ip-address

Comment: if you use the whole of `10.0.0.0/8` as a single network, then `10.0.0.255` and `10.0.1.0` are perfectly valid host addresses to use. Though, I do wonder if it's necessary or sensible to use all that as a single block, all 16.7 million addresses. In any case, are you sure you want to do this in just Bash? Also, why would you want to do it in Bash? Actual programming languages like Perl and Python have libraries just for handling IP addresses, while in Bash, you'd pretty much need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you allow valid IP addresses such as `10.0.1.0/8` and `10.0.255.255/8` then you can use a monotonically incrementing 32-bit integer like this

```
# Seed with 10.0.0.0 = 167772160
echo $(( (10<<24) + (0<<16) + (0<<8) + 0 )) >counter

# Read the counter, increment, and produce IP address
read ip <counter
echo $((++ip)) >counter

printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" $(( (ip>>24)&255 )) $(( (ip>>16)&255 )) $(( (ip>>8)&255 )) $((ip&255))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do it in a one liner but this is possible to do with an `if` clause and modular arithmetic.

Something along the lines of this:

```
a = 2nd octet
b = 3rd octet
c = 4th octet

if ( mod(c+1, 255) == 0)
  if (mod(b+1, 255) == 0)
    if (mod(a+1, 255) == 0)
      print "sorry, out of IP numbers"
      end
    b = 0
    a = a+1
    continue
  c = 0
  b = b+1
else
  c = c+1
print 10.a.b.c
```

Untested, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This is no language, just some pseudo code to give the general idea of my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use read to separate octets:

```
IFS='.' read -r a b c d <<< 10.0.0.0
ip=$(((a<<24)+(b<<16)+(c<<8)+d))
((ip++))
printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" $(((ip>>24)&255)) $(((ip>>16)&255)) $(((ip>>8)&255)) $((ip&255))
```